# How to save the state of my fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a simple app, in the home screen it has 4 tabs. Each tab is a fragment. In one of the fragments, I have a `ListView` that displays some songs. Nothing is stored locally, I populate the `ListView` with network calls (to the iTunes API, to my own server). If I click on a list item (a song), it starts a new activity that searches Youtube for that song. When I click back, it's as if the previous activity is started from scratch. How do I retain the scroll position of the `ListView` ?, It also goes back to the first fragment (the leftmost one in the `viewpager`). How do I make it return back to the fragment that the user clicked the song in?

Comment: Are you handling `onBackPressed` in your newly called `Activity`?

Comment: Did you tried something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try overriding the `onBackPressed` method in the called `Activity` and call `finish()` in that.